# Free Storage on Live USB Not Equal to USB's Capacity

Tags: storage

I created a live USB by downloading Ubuntu for desktop and then used Rufus to make the USB bootable. When I plug the USB into my computer while running Windows, the USB says that there is 27.2 GB of free space out of 28.6 GB. However, when I boot Ubuntu and click properties, it tells me that there is only 5.9 GB of free space left on my drive. Can someone please explain this to me or offer a way to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

What you're seeing is the root partition of the usb drive. The remaining space might either be unformatted or might be on another partition. Typically other partitions would be visible as other "subdevices": If your usb drive is recognized as `/dev/sda`, then the root partition might be `/dev/sda1` and the other (in your case larger) partition would be on `/dev/sda2`. If the remaining memory is formatted as an other partition, you might try to mount it separately (e.g. `pmount /dev/sda2` in the above example). Otherwise, you might be successful using `fdisk` to format the free space. Note the "might".

Comment: How do I do this? I'm sorry Im really new to this stuff and I don't know all the coding stuff. Do you think you could give me some steps?

Comment: Open a terminal and type `ls /sys/block`. That should show a list of "block" devices, i.e. devices that operate as some kind of storage device. Is there anything with a name that starts with "sd"? That would probably be your usb drive's device name. It is a separate directory. So you can just type `ls /sys/block/sda/` (or whatever the device name was). That would again list a couple of names, amoung others probably something like "sda1", "sda2", ... Those are partitions on the device. Can you see those?